# Openlayers 2 - how to effectively debug rendering failed

Tags: openlayers-2

When rendering multiple layers on a map, only one layer renders, the last layer in the array when looking at `myMap.layers`

On the layers which don't render, the features which are not rendered are held in `myMap.layers.unrenderedFeatures`

How can I debug ***WHY*** they weren't rendered? Is there any more information anywhere that will highlight the issue?

I haven't included code at this stage as it's a messy legacy system and would like to debug myself if possible to get a better understanding of what it's doing and why it's not rendering.

[I did look at the docs but they're not particularly helpful](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.unrenderedFeatures)